# Laravel how to write search query with multiple conditions but where records under the same user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a database with inventory products. Also, I have many users where products belonged to different users.
So I need to write a query with multiple conditions, where search needs to be in different table columns, so it will be a couple of `->orWhere()` statements. But the search needs to find all the products that belonged to the same user. But if I have many `->orWhere()` conditions, query starts searching the products under other users where other queries conditions match ("title" or "product_number").

So how can I change my code, where I can get all products with search keyword where the products under the same user?

Here is my code:

```
public function searchProduct(Request $search){
    $search_item = $search->search;
    $user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
    $inventory = Inventory::where('client_id', $user->client_id)
                            ->where('product_number', 'like', "%{$search_item}%")
                            ->orWhere('title', 'like', "%{$search_item}%")
                            ->orWhere('other_product_numbers', 'like', "%{$search_item}%")
                            ->with(['deliveryRecord', 'orderInRecord', 'sellRecord'])
                            ->paginate(50);

    $cleint_currency = SettingsClientCurrency::where('client_id', $user->client_id)->first();

    $inventory_products = Inventory::where('client_id', $user->client_id)->with('orderInRecord')->get();
    $inventory_total = 0;
    foreach ($inventory_products as $product) {
        $ordersin = $product->orderInRecord;
        foreach ($ordersin as $orderin) {
            $inventory_total += $orderin['price'] * $orderin['units'];

        }
    }

    return view('layouts.inventory.inventory')
            ->with('inventory', $inventory)
            ->with('inventory_total', $inventory_total)
            ->with('cleint_currency', $cleint_currency)
            ->with('user', $user);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use two where clause with a callback function in the second where clause. that will get your desired result

```
$inventory = Inventory::where('client_id', $user->client_id)
                       ->where(function ($query) use ($search_item) {
                           $query->where('product_number', 'like', "%{$search_item}%")
                                 ->orWhere('title', 'like', "%{$search_item}%")
                                 ->orWhere('other_product_numbers', 'like', "%{$search_item}%");
                       })
                       ->with(['deliveryRecord', 'orderInRecord', 'sellRecord'])
                       ->paginate(50);
```